# How to check for "autopoweroff" option on a non-active profile?

Tags: macos

I would like to check the value of `autopoweroff` and `autopoweroffdelay` settings for the "Battery Power" profile while running "AC Power" profile (precisely regardless of what profile is currently active).

The `pmset -g` command returns only values for the current profile and `-b` option (apply the settings to battery) works only for setting the options not reading them (cannot be used with `-g`).

Is there any other way/command that would allow checking the values?

Comment: Have you tried: `pmset -g profiles`

Comment: No, I have not (until now). `man` page does not mention it. Anyway I don't understand its output - it shows al profiles `autopoweroff 1` while if I disconnected the power cable and run `pmset -g` I get ` autopoweroff 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual `pmset -g custom` displays "*custom settings for all power sources*". It seems those "*custom settings*" are in fact all settings as displayed by `pmset -g` for current profile:

```
# pmset -g custom
Battery Power:
 lidwake              1
 autopoweroff         0
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 standbydelay         10800
 standby              1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 displaysleep         2
 sleep                1
 acwake               0
 halfdim              1
 lessbright           1
 disksleep            10
AC Power:
 lidwake              1
 autopoweroff         0
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 standbydelay         10800
 standby              1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             1
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 womp                 0
 displaysleep         10
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                0
 acwake               0
 halfdim              1
 disksleep            10
```

---

Alternatively the values can be checked by directly reading from `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.PowerManagement.plist`

```
# cat /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.PowerManagement.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ActivePowerProfiles</key>
    <dict>
        <key>AC Power</key>
        <integer>-1</integer>
        <key>Battery Power</key>
        <integer>-1</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>Custom Profile</key>
    <dict>
        <key>AC Power</key>
        <dict>
            <key>AutoPowerOff Delay</key>
            <integer>14400</integer>
            <key>AutoPowerOff Enabled</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>DarkWakeBackgroundTasks</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Disk Sleep Timer</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
            <key>Display Sleep Timer</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
            <key>Display Sleep Uses Dim</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>GPUSwitch</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>Hibernate File</key>
            <string>/var/vm/sleepimage</string>
            <key>Hibernate Mode</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
            <key>PrioritizeNetworkReachabilityOverSleep</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Standby Delay</key>
            <integer>10800</integer>
            <key>Standby Enabled</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>System Sleep Timer</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>TTYSPreventSleep</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>Wake On AC Change</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Wake On Clamshell Open</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>Wake On LAN</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>Battery Power</key>
        <dict>
            <key>AutoPowerOff Delay</key>
            <integer>14400</integer>
            <key>AutoPowerOff Enabled</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>DarkWakeBackgroundTasks</key>
            <false/>
            <key>Disk Sleep Timer</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
            <key>Display Sleep Timer</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>Display Sleep Uses Dim</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>GPUSwitch</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>Hibernate File</key>
            <string>/var/vm/sleepimage</string>
            <key>Hibernate Mode</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
            <key>ReduceBrightness</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>Standby Delay</key>
            <integer>10800</integer>
            <key>Standby Enabled</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>System Sleep Timer</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>TTYSPreventSleep</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>Wake On AC Change</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Wake On Clamshell Open</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>SystemPowerSettings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>DestroyFVKeyOnStandby</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```